# Difference between computational complexity theory and complexity theory

Tags: complexity-theory

I read that complexity theory is the study of complex systems. While I associate computational complexity theory with classification of problems.

Comment: Computational complexity theory is the study of?

Comment: The two have (virtually) nothing to do with each other.